# Changing Emac Editor's (C) Syntax Highlighting in Linux?

Tags: linux, emacs

I can't read most of my code because the syntax highlighting is too dark; I've tried to follow the steps on other posts (such as the M-x customize-face command), but I get an error stating that the command wasn't found. I'm pretty clueless about emacs but am required to use it for a class - could someone give me a step-by-step of how to change the colors of the fonts/highlighting?

Comment: You might try asking in emacs.stackexchange.com, you'll find more Emacs expertise there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are really clueless about emacs I can suggest one of two things:

1. In your emacs menu bar, pick options -> customize emacs and change the theme you're using. Don't forget to save after you're done!
2. Get some customization file over the web\ from someone with colors you like and add it to your init. If you already have a customization file, edit the color. here's an example of such a line:
   `(custom-set-faces '(default ((t (:stipple nil :background "gray95" :foreground "#000000" :inverse-video nil :box nil :strike-through nil :overline nil :underline nil :slant normal :weight normal :height 150 :width normal :family "adobe-courier")))))`

   Elaboration on #2:
   emacs uses .emacs to start, check the file (it should be in your homedir ~/.emacs). 
   In order to load a file, add `(load-file "your_file_and_path")` to this file.
   e.g.
   `(load-file "/users/someuser/.xemacs/custom.el")`